# Understanding Java Random next Integer with bound algorithm

Tags: java, random, integer

I'm looking at the way the Java Random library generates an integer given an upper bound, but I don't quite understand the algorithm. In the docs it says:

> The algorithm is slightly tricky. It rejects values that would result
> in an uneven distribution (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible
> by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n. The
> worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2,
> and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.

But I really don't see how this implementation takes this into account, specifically the `while` condition in the code. To me it seems that this would (almost) always succeed with 50% success rate. Especially when looking at very low values for `bound` (which I think is used a lot when imposing a bound). It seems to me like the condition in the `while` is just checking the sign of `bits`, so why bother with the line they use?

```
public int nextInt(int bound) {
   if (bound <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bound must be positive");

      if ((bound & -bound) == bound)  // i.e., bound is a power of 2
        return (int)((bound * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

      int bits, val;
      do {
          bits = next(31);
          val = bits % bound;
      } while (bits - val + (bound-1) < 0);
      return val;
 }
```

Comment: it's interesting that `ThreadLocalRandom::nextInt` is different in the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `bits - val + (bound-1) < 0` is actually checking whether `bits - val + (bound-1)` *overflows*. `bits` is always equal to or greater than `val`, and `bound` is always positive, so there is no way for the LHS to be positive under normal circumstances.

We can think of the `< 0` as `> Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Let's plot a graph of `bits - val + (bound - 1)`. I have made one on desmos [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ya3avisrqb). Let's say `bound` is 100 (small bound):

[image]

The x axis is `bits` and y axis is `bits - val + (bound-1)`, and I have added lines on both the x and y axes to indicate `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Note that `bits` is bounded by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

At this scale, you can see that `bits - val + (bound-1)` seems to never overflow. If you zoom *a lot*, you'll see:

[image]

Note that there is a tiny range of values of `bits` for which `bits < Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but `bits - val + (bound - 1) > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

For `b = (1 << 30) + 1`, the graph looks like:

[image]

Any `b` that is greater than `1 << 30` overflows. Hence the 1/2 chance of rejecting the bounds as the documentation said.